# explosion not spawning attached to parent gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine, triggers

So I'm trying to get my vehicle to play an explosion when colliding with an enemy vehicle and have succeeded in making the explosion appear but when doing so it is cloned outside of the parent object and gets left behind when collision happens at a speed so the actual player car doesn't look like its exploding but instead travels past the explosion prefab. Any ideas on how to fix this would be much appreciated. Thanks

```c#
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (col.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        PlayExplosion();
    }
}


void PlayExplosion()
{
    GameObject explosion = (GameObject)Instantiate(ExplosionGo);
    //set the position of the explosion
    explosion.transform.position = transform.position;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to either manually set the parent:

```c#
explosion.transform.parent = transform;
```

Or supply a parent transform in the `Instantiate` parameters:

```c#
GameObject explosion = (GameObject)Instantiate(ExplosionGo, transform);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply man, much appreciated, i tried both ways and they both work perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You need to set explosion transform a child of your car transform/ Try this:

```c#
void PlayExplosion()
{
    GameObject explosion = (GameObject)Instantiate(ExplosionGo);
    explosion.transform.SetParent(transform, false);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the speedy reply , your answer works perfectly @obywan also having problems destroying the explosion afterwards as instead of detroying the explosion prefab it destroys the actual car itself

Comment: no worries i managed to figure out how i can do it by putting the destroy function in a totally different script and attaching it to the explosion prefab